# fetch data from multiple tabels

Tags: php, search, laravel

i have some table,one of them is user table that i want fetch id from this table by searching username and second one is prize_info table that i want  to fetch user_id from here by searching a prize,after all i want fetch just prize_info.user_id and user.id.what is the best way for this search part in laravel4?? here is my codes

```
     $search = '%'.Input::get('keywords').'%';
    $pages      = DB::table('user')
    ->select('user.id','user.username')
    ->where('username', 'LIKE', $search)->get();

    $blogitems  = DB::table('prize_info')
    ->select('prize_info.id', 'prize_info.prize_name', 'prize_info.user_id')
    ->where('prize_name', 'LIKE', $search)->get();
```

what is your idea about above codes?????
and i check the result by this line but it does not work!

```
$results = $pages->union($blogitems)->take(30)->get();
```

please help me!best regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you used Laravel's [Eloquent ORM Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) to do  this. You can easily fetch related record using the available relationships;

1. One-to-One
2. One-to-Many
3. BelongsTo
4. BelongsToMany
5. HasMany
6. HasOne
7. Polymorphic Tables (using pivot tables)

Comment: may you explain more????i know about above relationship  but i thought
we can not use relation for searching between multiple tables!
if it is possible please explain it more!thanks a lot

Comment: when you have written the search query, the relationship will help you retrieve the associated data you want stored in multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$search = '%'.Input::get('keywords').'%'
$results = DB::table('user')
                    ->select('user.id','user.username','prize_info.id', 'prize_info.prize_name', 'prize_info.user_id')
                    ->leftJoin('prize_info','user.id','prize_info.user_id')
                    ->take(30)
                    ->get();
```